# Set graphics to only use one third of a screen

Tags: display, resolution, screen, display-resolution

are here some hardcore users like that to be able to help me with my broken screen, where only the left third of a screen works?

I use an external monitor most of the time, but it would be really nice to be able to use the rest of my integrated screen here. I guess it will go with some one-liner..? But I have no idea where to start here, Google didn't give me anything useful.

Originally the resolution was HD, ie. `1366x768 px`.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44707/66248) by [Tim Kennedy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4721/tim-kennedy) on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) seems solid.

> Check out: http://howto-pages.org/ModeLines/ , they have a good
>   explanation of Xorg modelines.  Then go to
>   http://xtiming.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xtiming.pl and input the specs
>   for the size of the screen that you can use.  This will give you a
>   Modeline that you can add to your xorg.conf file.
>
> Fields 4, 5, 6, & 7 correspond to the following valudes:  HDisplay
>   HSyncStart HSyncEnd HTotal.
>
> By playing with fields 5 & 6, you'll be able to move the visible
>   portion of your screen either left or right, depending on which you
>   need.

It seems to not apply to the TTYs though.

Comment: so did you try it? did it work?